# Create a box of colours image

Tags: javascript, php, css, image, colors

I have been working on a web application that produces an image out of colours, having multiple divs works, but the load time is slow and until the image loads its timetaking, I would like to make a table like image with lots of colors extracted from an image and display them inside a web page. I don't know which language to use to create a color box other than the code I have, But I would like to get rid of divs and possibly make the GUI not in HTML but have it available in a browser!

My working code:

```
<style>
div {
    display:inline-block;
    width:2.6px;
    height:2.6px;
}
</style>
<?PHP
    $im = imagecreatefrompng('image.png');// open an image
    $image = Array(); //array of colors
    $image_x = 480; //image width
    $image_y = 272; //image height
    $x = 0; //x pixel in image
    $y = 0; //y pixel im image
    while ($x < $image_x && $y < $image_y) {
        $start_x = $x;
        $start_y = $y;
        $color_index = imagecolorat($im, $start_x, $start_y);
        $color_tran = imagecolorsforindex($im, $color_index);// make it human readable
        array_push($image, join(',', $color_tran));
        $x++;
        if($x > $image_x-1) {
            $x = 0;$y++;
        }
    }
    $i = 0;
    foreach ($image as $color) {
        $rgb = explode(",", $color);
        if($i > $image_x-1){
            $i = 0;echo "<br>";
        }
        echo "<div style='background-color:rgb(".implode(",",array_slice($rgb, 0, -1)).");'></div>";
        $i++;
    }
?>
```

Comment: If your code is working and you're just looking to improve on it, you'd be better off posting this at: http://codereview.stackexchange.com/

Comment: Thankyou, I will post it there! I just wanted to see some suggestions of web GUI other than HTML but thankyou Ill post it there!

Comment: Take a look at http://www.html5tutorial.info/html5-color.php

Comment: I know about that, The input only takes 1 color I need it to take 921600 colors in one table like GUI